# Livewire $this->resetPage() sometimes work, sometimes not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this component to render paginated results:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Accounts;

use App\Models\Account;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $search;
    public $accounts;

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->search) {
            $this->resetPage();
            $this->accounts = Account::search($this->search)
                ->orWhere('fullname', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')->orderBy('fullname')->paginate(12);
        } else {
            $this->accounts = Account::orderBy('fullname')->paginate(12);
        }

        return view('livewire.accounts.index', ['accounts' => $this->accounts]);
    }

    public function updatingSearch(): void
    {
        $this->resetPage();
    }
}
```

If I search for Accounts, sometimes the resetPage() works and the pagination links get adjusted/removed, but sometimes it ends up with "Showing 1 to 4 of 11 Results" and pagination links for 2 pages, but there are only 4 results.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Accounts;

use App\Models\Account;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $search;
    public $accounts;

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->search) {
            $this->accounts = Account::search($this->search)
                ->orWhere('fullname', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')->orderBy('fullname')->paginate(12);
        } else {
            $this->accounts = Account::orderBy('fullname')->paginate(12);
        }

        return view('livewire.accounts.index', ['accounts' => $this->accounts]);
    }

  public function updatingsearch(): void
  {
   $this->resetPage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).